# Can I use Node.js for the back end and Python for the AI calculations?

Tags: python, node.js, artificial-intelligence, spyder

I am trying to create a website in Node.js. Though, as I am taking a course on how to use Artificial Intelligence and would like to implement such into my program. Therefore, I was wondering if it was feasible to connect Python Spyder to a Node.js based web application with somewhat ease.

Comment: Yes you can lauch python script from Node

Comment: not overly familiar with Spyder but it seems to be an IDE targeted at scientific python applications rather than an AI engine itself, so you might be a little confused on some things here.  However, whatever AI engine you end up running should ideally have some kind of API that can be called in a language agnostic manner the same way any language can call any web API regardless of what language the API itself is written in. This kind of loose coupling is very helpful and makes everything more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways i am aware of which you can do this
1) Use child_process library

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('python yourscript.py', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err) {
return;
}
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

You can check this article if you want step by step guide. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-method/

2) Better method would be to create a API which you can later call using AJAX or whichever library you prefer. You can use microframework such as flask to create a server which then you can call using NodeJs.
Tutorial to convert your machine learning code to API:
https://towardsdatascience.com/publishing-machine-learning-api-with-python-flask-98be46fb2440

```
axios.post( your_api_address , {
MLparametre1: 'somevalue',
MLparametre2: 'somevalue',
MLparametre3: 'somevalue',
MLparametre4: 'somevalue',
})
```

Or you can just pass a list or dictionary object. https://flaviocopes.com/node-axios/ you can learn more about axios here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is possible. There are a few ways you can do this. You can use the child_process library, as mentioned above. Or, you can have a Python API that takes care of the AI stuff, which your Node app communicates with.

The latter example is what I prefer as most my projects run on containers as micro services on Kubernates.